# React dependency module is looking for image source in parent module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **footer** React module which will be installed as a dependency in several other projects.

When try to use an image element inside the **footer** module, it's trying to find the image source in the parent module instead in its own `/resources/img` folder.

below is the code snipit.

```
<img className="footer-dropdown" src="/resources/img/footer_arrow_default.svg"/>
```

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?...

Comment: You could try to import the image as an element and just set it to the `src` instead of putting the path in the `src`

Comment: @DennisVash no I'm not using CRA, so looking for a solution without importing it. By the way this **footer*** is a bit small module.

Comment: Are you using webpack? Please ask a complete question with all relevant information

Comment: @Sabbin, tried to import, but looks like it needs additional configuration changes since I'm not using create react app, so trying to use image directly if possible.

Comment: @DennisVash, apologies for missing relevant details, I'm using **grunt**.

Answer (score 2):

If your project bootstrapped with CRA you need to import the image.

[See adding images in CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/):

> With webpack, using static assets like images and fonts works
>   similarly to CSS.
>
> You can import a file right in a JavaScript module. This tells webpack
>   to include that file in the bundle. Unlike CSS imports, importing a
>   file gives you a string value. **This value is the final path you can
>   reference in your code**, e.g. as the src attribute of an image or the
>   href of a link to a PDF.

For image path:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image
console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png
function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}
export default Header;
```

As for rendering a `svg`:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
      <Logo />
    </div>
  );
}
```